# Error in Import Python.h file to C program

Tags: python, c, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble importing Python.h to a C program.
I have 4 files, `hellofunc.c`, `hellomake.c`, `hellomake.h` and `Makefile`.
The `hellomake.h`, `Python.h` and all related Python files are in a `include` folder.
And the rest is in the `program` folder.

```
├───include
│   ├───cpython
│   └───internal
├───lib
└───program
```

The code of `hellofunc.c` file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hellomake.h>

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {

  printf("Hello makefiles!\n");

  return;
}
```

The code of `hellomake.h` is:

```
void myPrintHelloMake(void);
```

The code of `hellomake.c` is:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <hellomake.h>

int main() {
  // call a function in another file
  myPrintHelloMake();

  Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World from Embedded Python!!!')");
    Py_Finalize();

  return(0);
}
```

The code of `Makefile` is:

```
IDIR =../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

hellomake: $(_OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

The error that I got is:

```
gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I../include -lm
hellomake.o:hellomake.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
hellomake.o:hellomake.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
hellomake.o:hellomake.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:56: hellomake] Error 1
```

Comment: It looks like you have to link some libraries related to Python.

Comment: I included the Python libraries in the Makefile.